# What is the difference between a Template and Template-Attribute Structure in KMIP?

Tags: protocols, kmip

I'm currently learning and developing KMIP (Spec 1.0) using the open source library KMIP4J. I was looking through the use cases offered as examples in the spec sheet, and I am stuck trying to differentiate the use of a Template and a Template-Attribute Structure.

What is the difference between these two Use Cases? Both have the Cryptographic Algorithm and Cryptographic Length Attribute, but I don't understand the difference between them.

- [Use Case 3.1.4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/usecases/v1.0/cs01/kmip-usecases-1.0-cs-01.html#_Toc262822056), which uses a Template.
- [Use Case 3.1.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/usecases/v1.0/cs01/kmip-usecases-1.0-cs-01.html#_Toc262822053), which uses a Template-Attribute Structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the [KMIP Specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.3/os/kmip-spec-v1.3-os.pdf), there are two different types of objects: *Managed Objects* and *Base Objects*.

- A **Managed Object** refers to:

  > Objects stored and maintained by a key management system [KMIP Spec, Section 1]

  Examples of Managed Objects: Certificate, Symmetric Key, Public Key, Private Key, Template
- A **Base Object** refers to:

  > Objects used within the messages of the protocol but not managed by the key management system. Base Objects are components of Managed Objects.
  >   [KMIP Spec, Section 2.1]

  Examples of Base Objects: Attribute, Credential, Key Value, Template-Attribute Structure

---

- A **Template** is a type of Managed Object.

  > A Template is the named Managed Object containing the client-settable attributes of a Managed Cryptographic Object (i.e., a stored, named list of attributes). Attributes specified in a Template apply to any object created that references the Template by name. 
  >   [KMIP Spec, Section 2.2.6]
- A **Template-Attribute Structure** is a type of Base Object.

  > Template-Attribute Structures are used in various operations to provide the desired attribute values and/or template names in the request and to return the actual attribute values in the response.
  >   [KMIP Spec, Section 2.1.8]

---

So, let's look at the use cases you've pointed to:

In Use Case 3.1.1:

1. The client sends a Create request, which contains the Object Type (Symmetric Key) and a *Template-Attribute Structure* containing the list of desired attribute values for that key:

   - Cryptographic Algorithm
   - Cryptographic Length
   - Cryptographic Usage Mask.

In Use Case 3.1.4:

1. The client uses the Register operation to register a *Template*, containing a specific set of Attributes:

   - Cryptographic Algorithm
   - Cryptographic Length
   - Name, referring to the name of the Template to create: `Template1`
2. The client sends a Create request, which, like before, contains the Object Type (Symmetric Key) and a *Template-Attribute Structure*. However, this time the Template-Attribute Structure contains:

   - A reference to a *Template* named `Template1`, indicating that the operation should use the attributes specified by `Template1` (which we know from step 1 are Cryptographic Algorithm and Cryptographic Length)
   - Name, referring the name of the Key: `key1`
   - Cryptographic Usage Mask

So the two operations essentially create the same Symmetric Key with the same attribute values, but the second case uses a pre-defined Template (and, trivially, adds a key name), while the first does not.

---

A side note:

The [KMIP 1.0 Specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.0/kmip-spec-1.0.pdf) is fairly out of date at this point. KMIP 1.3 was released in December 2015. I mention this specifically because the *Template* Structure is deprecated as of 1.3.

Comment: Thank you for your response!! and completely answer!! KMIP 1.3 Spec does not support Template Structure? I did not know that. THANK YOU!!